# Select All Records From One Table And Matching Record From Other Table or Null (if not exist)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables: `tblCompany` and `tblCompanyAddress`.

I'm looking for a MS Access SQL query for showing 2 columns:

- Column1 --> All Cname from tblCompany
- Column2 --> Cadr from tblCompanyAddress if Catyp = 1 or show Null (if not exist or Catyp <>1)

tblCompany:

| id | Cname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |

tblCompanyAddress:

| id | tblCompanyKey | Cadr | Catyp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | po | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | kk | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | dd | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | er | 3 |
| 5 | 4 | er | 1 |

Expected result

| id | Cname | Cadr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | po |
| 2 | B |  |
| 3 | C |  |
| 4 | D | er |

Can anyone help?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LEFT JOIN` garantees that all rows from company are present.

To get only Cadr from Ctype 1 you need in Access an Subselect

```
SELECT
tblCompany.* ,tblCompanyAddress.[Cadr]
FROM tblCompany 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *  FROM tblCompanyAddress WHERE tblCompanyAddress.Catyp = 1) AS tblCompanyAddress ON tblCompany.ID = tblCompanyAddress.tblCompanyKey
```

Resuls in

[image]